# Define and use variable in OpenResty config file

Tags: nginx, lua, nginx-location, nginx-config, openresty

I want to define a variable and use it in the location block in OpenResty config file.
Variable is defined same follow:

```
location /projects {
   set $my_var '';
   content_by_lua_block {
      ngx.var.my_var = "h@3265";
   }

   header_filter_by_lua '
      local val = ngx.header["x-ausername"]
      if val then
         if (val ~= "sample3")
         and (val ~= ngx.var.my_var) -- this variable does not work
         and (val ~= "sample2")
         and (val ~= "sample1")
         and (val ~= "anonymous") then
            return ngx.exit(400)
         end
      end
   ';

   proxy_pass        http://MYSERVER.LOCAL:6565;
   proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
   access_log off;
}
```

But doesn't pars `ngx.var.my_var`.
How can I define a variable and use it in any part of `nginx.conf` file?

Comment: I'm confused; you're using `proxy_pass` and `content_by_lua` at the same time, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I wanna at first checked `x-ausername` in request header if that equal with my variable then that username permitted to login to my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, I changed config file into follow and that works fine.

```
location /projects {

   header_filter_by_lua '
      local my_var = "h%403265"             #**Note**
      local val = ngx.header["x-ausername"]
      if val then
         if (val ~= "sample3")
         and (val ~= my_var) 
         and (val ~= "sample2")
         and (val ~= "sample1")
         and (val ~= "anonymous") then
            return ngx.exit(400)
         end
      end
   ';

   proxy_pass        http://MYSERVER.LOCAL:6565;
   proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
   access_log off;
}
```

Note: in config file for accept `@` in a variable should used to percent encoding. So,`@` equal to `%40` (h@3265 --> h%403265).

Comment: The right place for acces controll is the aptly named `access_by_lua_block`, not `header_filter_by_lua` which only runs [much later](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2137369/15272097/77d1c09e-1a37-11e6-97ef-d9767035fc3e.png).

Comment: I checked `access_by_lua_block` but it can control through request's IP. but I need only checked `x-ausername` in request header and then if that equal with my variable then that username permitted to login to my website.

Comment: The problem is that `header_filter_by_lua` runs at the end of the content phase, so you're wasting resources connecting to the proxy only to then throw the entire response away.

Comment: To clarify: *header_filter* is for filtering **response** headers before they get sent to the client, **not** to filter the request headers before handling the request.

Comment: You're right and thank you for your attention. But I wanna control on users based on username and while a user fill username and password fields I couldn't check it until authentication process completed. So as you said I should filter it on response header.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to set a const value to your variable - just use `set $my_var 'h@3265';` directive and avoid `content_by_lua_block`.

It is not possible to use `proxy_pass` and `content_by_lua_block` in the same place because both are content phase directives.
`content_by_lua_block` just ignored in your config.

If you need to use more complex Lua logic to set the variable - use [set_by_lua_block](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#set_by_lua_block)